# SQL Max (Quantity*ProductPrice)

Tags: sql, ms-access, max

I am trying to answer the question of which product ID and ProductName brought in more revenue than the average revenue earned from a product in the store.

I have the following code:

```
Select ProductName, SupplierName, MAX(Quantity*ProductPrice) as TotalRev
From Products
Where MAX(TotalRev) > AVG(TotalRev)
```

Yet this results in an error.

Sample Data

```
ProductID  ProductName  SupplierName ProductType Quantity ProductPrice
10001      GreenJacket  GAP          Jackets     100      $10
10002      StarEarrings Oldnavy      Accessories 200      $5
10003     YellowDress   BRP          Dress       150      $10
```

Ideally, I would want the code to spit out the ProductID and Product name where the product brought in more revenue that the average revenue.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help . . . both other people and probably you to understand the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Please see Edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `having` clause and a subquery:

```
Select ProductId, ProductName,
       SUM(Quantity*ProductPrice) as TotalRev
From Products
group by ProductId, ProductName
having SUM(Quantity*ProductPrice) >= (select avg(revenue) 
                                      from (select sum(p2.quantity * p2.ProductPrice) as revenue
                                            from products as p2
                                            group by p2.ProductId, p2.ProductName
                                           ) as p3
                                      );
```

I would advise you to run the subquery in the `having` clause so that you fully understand what it is doing.